# 'more' in Mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I would like to know how to output a large document using something like unix's `more` command in a Mongo shell.

I have a large document that I want to inspect, but it quickly fills my terminals maximum height. As a result I cannot see the beginning part of it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think thats is possible in MongoDB. You can export your data into file by `mongoexport`. Or, you can try MongoDB `projection` Or, via JS, create script and split data into small pieces. The better way is use MongoDB GUI, like Robomongo which is fantastic for working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, that is pretty easy and there is no need for a GUI:

```
mongo  --eval 'db = db.getSiblingDB("yourdb");
  c = db.yourCollection.find({"answer":42},{"_id":0,"question":1});
  while(c.hasNext()){
    printjson(c.next())
  }' | less
```

(Indented for readability, works nevertheless)